# Bad path to API controller in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Laravel structure like this:

```
app/
   Http/
       Controllers/
          Api/
          Auth/
              RegisterController
```

and  the **API route:**

```
 // AUTH
   Route::namespace('Api')->group(function () {
     Route::post('password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail');
     Route::post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset');
     Route::post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');
});
```

But the  POST request to ***http://domain.xx/api/register***  return an internal error:

> Class App\Http\Controllers\Api\Auth\RegisterController does not exist
>   in file...

I've tried pointing to '..\Auth\RegisterController@register' but I got same error:

> Class ..\Auth\RegisterController does not exist in file

It should be simple to fix lol... but... can you help me?

Comment: As per your folder structure api and auth is at same level but you are using it as parent child

Comment: move your Auth directory inside Api Folder or you have to make changes in routing  Route::post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register'); outside Route group

Answer (score 0):

**Routes Group**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api', 'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers'], function()
{
    Route::post('password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail');
     Route::post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset');
     Route::post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');
});
```

> You can delete folder App\Http\Controllers\Api, you can use PREFIX on
>   your group routes

Comment: It return the error: "The POST method is not supported for this route"

Comment: Laravel consider the 'namespace' = 'App\Http\Controllers' in this case so you don't need to add it.   I can use  namespace='Auth' removing "Auth" inside the group.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it

```
 // AUTH
   Route::namespace('Auth')->group(function () {
   Route::post('password/email', 'ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail');
   Route::post('password/reset', 'ResetPasswordController@reset');
   Route::post('register', 'RegisterController@register');
```

});